# cursor count always returns 0 in sqlitedatabase android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have simple method which checks for existing username in sqlitedatabase. if it exists it return true else false.

but cursor.getcount() always return 0, no matter how i change the query.

here is my code:

```
public boolean IsUsernameexists(String username)
    {
        boolean b=false;
        int count=0;


        Cursor cursor=mDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{USER_NAME,PASSWORD,SECURITY_Q_1,SECURITY_Q_2,SECURITY_Q_3}, " user_name=?", new String[]{USER_NAME}, null, null, null);




        Logger.log(Level.INFO, "Get count of username exists=", "" +  cursor.getCount());// always return 0
        if(count>=1)
        {
            b=true;
            Logger.log(Level.INFO,TAG,"Username already exists inside table");
            return b;


        }
        Logger.log(Level.INFO,TAG,"Username is new  inside table");
        return b;

    }
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong in the code; could be that way you put the data or incorrect String variable

Comment: yes i have debugged in proper way, the value of string is going inside method

Comment: get the database and open it and see of there are data in your tables after saving.

Comment: 1. cause: the username is not equal to the user name in Your table. 2. cause: the column user_name is spelled wrong for example in capital letters USER_NAME instead of user_name. 3. cause: Your database/table is not created. Could You exclude all three scenarios?

Comment: database is creating , i can see in sqlite browser

Comment: however, my database connection has been made singelton class

Comment: and the other two cases?

Comment: column name is spelled right ,checked it 1000 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass the constant `USER_NAME` into the query instead of the method parameter `username`. Maybe you also have another value in the `USER_NAME` constant as the value `user_name` you provide as the column to query.

Try to change the line:

```
Cursor cursor=mDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{USER_NAME,PASSWORD,SECURITY_Q_1,SECURITY_Q_2,SECURITY_Q_3}, " user_name=?", new String[]{USER_NAME}, null, null, null);
```

to:

```
Cursor cursor=mDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{USER_NAME,PASSWORD,SECURITY_Q_1,SECURITY_Q_2,SECURITY_Q_3}, USER_NAME+"=?", new String[]{username}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: exactly this was happening, i don't know why .

Comment: same thing is happening in this query

Comment: Cursor cursor=mDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{USER_NAME, PASSWORD},
                USER_NAME + "=?"+" "+"AND"+" "+PASSWORD+"=?" , new String[]{username,password}, null, null, null);

Comment: cursor.getCount()  always reurn 0

Comment: I don't see any error in that query. Are the passwords in the database encrypted in some way?

Comment: nope same thing is happening ,cursor.getCount() always return 0.

Comment: i am passing (String username,String password) as a parameter to this query